# Does Windows C# AddIn for Excel work for Mac?

Tags: c#, excel, macos, compatibility

I have an AddIn for Excel, written in C#, using Framework 4.0.
I want to make it work on Mac. Is this possible?

Comment: If you can use the addin when compiled in Mono you MIGHT be able to make it work. Mono support .net 3.5 and 4.0 preview. I do not know if 4.0 preview is enough for the addin but it's your only solution to run on IOS, the other solution that is NOT under IOS is Parallel with windows installed with .net4.0 and excel.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
What about if I create a new RibbonTab for Excel with Custom UI Editor? Does that work for Mac ?

Comment: the problem is not the addin. the problem it's that it is done in .net language. Either you run mono and wish that it works or rewrite the tool as a macro.

Comment: We gave up using the .NET Addin. I am now making a XML for the Ribbon Tab and i will write the code in vba. That will solve the problem, right?

Comment: Well maybe. Back then microsoft changed the VBA to AppleScript on MAC so you had to write the code in both script language. in 2010 ~ish they came back with VBA in both version but i have seen different behavior in some occasion when running on Mac vs PC. You will have to test each phase on both and see if the code run the same way but yes both will run the VBA code. You may have issue with rounding and lookup on Mac and things like that.

Comment: [here a quick list of few issues](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac027.htm) you have to workaround when planning to make it work on mac

Comment: I made a new Ribbon Tab with Custom UI Editor, added buttons and VBA code, works perfectly on Windows, but on Mac, the Ribbon Tab can't be seen.